# Re-order array on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have `array[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Onclick select button I'm able to increment array. But on click remove button, I want to reset array e.g. [1,2,3,4] if I remove number 2 array then order should become [1,2,3]. Basically, re-order in increment order.

[**Fiddle Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/fw8rep7L/5/)

```
var spl = $('.cc').text();
var tc = spl.split("").sort();
var l = 0; 
var p = [];
l = l % tc.length;
$('.cc').text(tc[l]);
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you even need an array in this case? The values will be incremental up to the `length` of the array, so just use `array.length`...?

Comment: If you see my fiddle demo, you'll understand. `array` is required for many purposes. Haven't I tried `l = l % tc.length`. I see problem when add and remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to update the numbers of each element:

```
$('.counter').filter(function() {
    return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > cnt;
}).each(function() {
    var c = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(--c);
});
```

A working example based on your code:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r_costa/751630ez/)

Comment: Hi R. Costa, Thanks, you have given a great solution. I want to same to apply on list hover with +1. And it's working fine while select but when click on remove it doesn't work proper. I have applied filter method as you have done. please see [**fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/751630ez/2/).

Comment: Remove your second filter and change line 39 to var cnt2 = $('.counter2').text(n);